# Show specific orders to custom role

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am building a website for a company, they have managers and employees and managers need to have a look ONLY over their department orders. I'm not sure how to approach the problem...

Should i create some custom order status for each department (which has 10-50 employees each time) and display that custom order status to one user role or should i try something else ?

Thank you for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer !

What this does : We get the `user_id` that did the order, if it's a certain number we assign it to a store manager id. We then create a meta_key in the order with this `store_manager_id` and we filter orders for all shop managers with the meta key that match their id.

I'll upgrade the code later with a switch to add multiples users and store managers.

```
function before_checkout_create_order($order, $data) {

    $store_manager_id = '';

    if ($order->get_user_id() === 5) {
        // Manually assigning the _store_manager_id using the user id, yours will differ
        $store_manager_id = 7;
    }

    $order->update_meta_data('_store_manager_id', $store_manager_id);
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'before_checkout_create_order', 20, 2);

function custom_admin_shop_manager_orders($query) {
    global $pagenow;
    $qv = &$query->query_vars;

    $currentUserRoles = wp_get_current_user()->roles;
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    if (in_array('shop_manager', $currentUserRoles)) {
        if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' && 
                isset($qv['post_type']) && $qv['post_type'] == 'shop_order' ) {
            // I use the meta key from step 1 as a second parameter here
            $query->set('meta_key', '_store_manager_id');
            // The value we want to find is the $user_id defined above
            $query->set('meta_value', $user_id);
        }
    }

    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'custom_admin_shop_manager_orders');
```